# Matrix represenation of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

Observe the matrix 
$$ A =\begin{pmatrix}
    6 & 2 \\ 
    2 & 3\\
\end{pmatrix}\in Mat_2(\mathbb{R})$$
and let $L = L_A: \mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^2}$ be the corresponding linear operator.
Let $V=(v_1,v_2)$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R^2}$ where: 
$$ v_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
    1  \\ 
    -2 \\
\end{pmatrix},
v_2 =\begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\ 
    1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Show that $L(v_1) = 2v_1$ and $L(v_2) = 7v_2$ and find the matrix representation $B =\ _v[L]_v$ for L with respect to $V$.

---

I have shown the first part:

$$L(v_1)=\begin{pmatrix}
    6 & 2 \\ 
    2 & 3\\
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ 
    -2 \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\ 
    -4 \\
\end{pmatrix}=2v_1$$
$$L(v_2)=\begin{pmatrix}
    6 & 2 \\ 
    2 & 3\\
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\ 
    1 \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    14 \\ 
    7 \\
\end{pmatrix}=7v_2$$

This is how far I have got with finding the matrix representation

$$_v[L]_v= ([L(v_1)]_v \ [L(v_2)]_v)=([2v_1]_v \ [7v_2]_v)$$
I am a bit unsure how to evaluate the last part, my instructor says that the matrix representation should be: $$ \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0\\ 
    0 & 7 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it:

> $$_v[L]_v= ([L(v_1)]_v \ [L(v_2)]_v)=([2v_1]_v \ [7v_2]_v)$$

Note $[2v_1]_V=\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $[7v_2]_V=\begin{bmatrix}0\\7\end{bmatrix}$ so

$([2v_1]_v \ [7v_2]_v)=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 7 \end{bmatrix}$

Note by definition given an ordered basis $\mathcal{B}=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_m\}$ for a vector space $V$ then for each $v\in V$
$$
v=x_1b_1+\cdots+x_mb_m
$$ 
for a unique scalar values $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m$ (use linear independence of $\mathcal{B}$ to show uniqueness and that $\mathcal{B}$ spans $V$ to show they exist).

Then the definition of $[v]_\mathcal{B}$ is

$$[v]_\mathcal{B}=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_m\end{bmatrix}$$.

That is the bracket is an invertible linear transformation $[\cdot]_\mathcal{B}:V \to \mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: Could you elaborate why $[2v_1]_V=\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\end{bmatrix}$ ? When I try to write it out I get another result

Comment: It's by definition, I've edited my post to elaborate.

Comment: I guess I have to read up on the definition again, as I still do not quite understand how $[2v_1]_v = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}$, but thanks for taking your time trying to explain it

Comment: $[2v_1]_V=2v_1+0v_2$ so it's 2 in the $v_1$ coordinate and 0 in the $v_2$ coordinate.

Comment: Just to clarify, so when i have to evaluate $[2v_1]_V$ I have to take the corresponding $v_1$ in the basis $V$ and find the scalar values, which must be $2v_1+0v_2$ - so if it would have been the case that $V = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$, then $[2v_1]_V = 2v_1+0v_2 + 0v_3 = \begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @Simbörg That is correct

Answer (score 0):

That's the meaning of matrix of linear map $T$ with respect to a basis $(b_1,b_2)$: if $T(b_1)=\alpha b_1+\beta b_2$ and $T(b_2)=\gamma b_1+\delta b_2$, then the matrix of $T$ with respect to that basis will be $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\alpha&\gamma\\\beta&\delta\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. In your case, $\alpha=2$, $\beta=\gamma=0$, and $\delta=7$ and so…